# Can a Ruby module be described as a singleton class?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, module

I'm trying to understand the purpose of a Ruby module from a design pattern perspective.

Is a Ruby module essentially just a class that is only initialized once?

`include MyModule`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A ruby class is a module you can make instances of.  Like a class, a module can have methods, but you cannot make an instance of a module.  That's the only difference between them.

In practice, modules are commonly used for:

- Name spaces
- Mixins
- To hold functions

## Name Space

Here's an example of a module used as a name space:

```
module MyLib
  class Foo
  end
  class Bar
  end
end
```

The full name of these classes is MyLib::Foo and MyLib::Bar.  Because they are contained in a namespace (which presumably is unique), the names Foo and Bar cannot conflict with a Foo or Bar defined in your program or in another library.

## Mixin

Here's a module used as a mix-in:

```
module Mixin
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end
```

Since you can't make an instance of the Mixin module, you get access to foo by including (mixing in) the module:

```
class MyClass
  include Mixin
end

MyClass.new.foo    # => foo
```

## Functions

Like a class, a module can hold functions that do not operate on any instance.  To do that, you define class methods in the module:

```
module SomeFunctions
  def self.foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end
```

A class method defined in a module is just like a class method defined in a class.  To call it:

```
SomeFunctions.foo    # => foo
```

Comment: I agree, but I think your third option is really just a perverse alternative implementation of your first. I see no reason why you should ever want to defined a singleton method on a module, unless perhaps if you were also using it as a mixin and wanted to hide that method from instances of the including class.

Comment: Your third example is just an example of a singleton class. It would work with any kind of object, not just a module.

Comment: @Borodin, Defining a module of functions is a common practice.  One good example is in the Ruby library itself: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Math.html

Comment: Jörg, I don't think so.  A singleton class has state, and methods that implicitly operate upon that state.  A function does not operate on some object's state.  It takes arguments and returns a result.  And, if impure, it has side-effects (I/O, etc.).  But it is not implicitly bound to some object (other than `main`, but that's really splitting hairs).

Comment: @WayneConrad: Huh? You're defining `foo` in `SomeFunctions`'s singleton class. The fact that `SomeFunctions` is a `Module` is completely irrelevant. It could be any other kind of object. And `foo` is *not* bound to `main`, it's bound to `SomeFunctions`. You could just as well have `def (SomeFunctions = Object.new).foo; puts 'foo' end; SomeFunctions.foo`.

Comment: @Jörg, Ah, yes, I was wrong about the binding.  Thank you for the correction.  Still, a function isn't _using_ its implicit binding.  I understand now how defining class methods in a function is a sort of singleton.  Still, when they are functions, they're not really being used as a singleton would normally be used.  They're just functions.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *class method* in Ruby. It's just a *singleton method* of the class object. Actually, there's no such thing as a singleton method either, it's just a regular instance method of the class object's singleton class. And, since every object has a singleton class, not just modules, there's nothing in your third point that is specific to modules. You are not using the fact that `SomeFunctions` is a module in any way. You could do exactly the same with a `String`, an `Array` or any other object.

Comment: What makes your methods "functions" is the fact that they are referentially transparent and that they don't access `self`, not the fact that they are defined in a module … which they aren't even, they are defined in a singleton class.

Answer (score 1):

Modules have two uses in Ruby: namespacing of constants and as mixins.

Namespacing of constants simply means that in

```
FOO = 1

module Bar
  FOO = 2
end

module Baz
  FOO = 3
end
```

there are three different `FOO`s in three different namespaces: one in the global namespace (which is actually `Object`), one in `Bar` and one in `Baz`.

The more interesting use case is mixins: a mixin is basically a class which is parameterized over its superclass. Or, to put it another way: a mixin is a class that can appear multiple times in the inheritance graph, each time with a different superclass.

Contrast this with multiple inheritance: in multiple inheritance, a class can only appear *once* in the inheritance graph, but it may have *multiple* superclasses. A mixin may appear *multiple* times in the inheritance graph, but each occurrence has only *one* superclass.

In particular, what happens in Ruby when you mix a module `M` into a class `C` is that an *actual* class (a so-called *include class*) is created (let's call it `M′`) whose method table, constant table and variable table pointers point to `M`'s method table, constant table and variable table, and that class `M′` becomes `C`'s superclass with the old superclass becoming `M′`'s superclass.

Answer (score 0):

A class is a module but a module is not a class. `Module` is literally the superclass of `Class`. If you know OOP, that's all you need to know.

Ruby modules are best used as namespaces and used in mixins.

Comment: I doubt it. In Ruby terms, Module is a special type of 'class' which cannot be instantiated

Comment: Do a `Class.superclass` in irb and it will give `Module`. However doing a `Module.class` will give `Class`. i.e. `Module` is an instance of `Class` and also it's superclass. :)