# Ruby Singleton, module vs class

Tags: ruby

I want to get in difference of implementation singleton pattern in ruby vs class and vs module.I'm talking about singleton with class methods only and no instances. As for me, it is logical to use

```
module Foo
  def self.foo= other
    @@foo=other
  end
  def self.foo
    @@foo
  end
end
```

but very often I see in others code `class Foo;....;end` and I want to understand why?If there is no instances and no sub classes `Module` is more convenient. Or may be I miss something?

The question is what is the diff between module and class in singleton pattern implementation?

Comment: Actually, there are many ways to implement Singletons in Ruby. I found the following article quite enlightening: https://www.practicingruby.com/articles/ruby-and-the-singleton-pattern-dont-get-along

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get an object in Ruby is to use, well, an object:

```
class << Foo = Object.new
  attr_accessor :foo
end
```

Using either a module or a class is overkill, both have features you don't need.

Comment: It is brilliant syntax idea! Thank you!

Comment: Love it, but isn't `Foo` actually a constant here (shouldn't it be `FOO`)?

Comment: @BorisB.: The OP used the spelling `Foo`, so that's what I used.

Comment: This is a very idiomatic and useful pattern to create one-off objects, without having to use `module`, `class` or `new`. It is  especially useful because you can also use `include` inside the singleton class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are objects whose class ensures that it is instantiated only once, and same instance is shared by all clients.

Ruby's [`Singleton`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) module helps in achieving this in convenient manner.

- A module cannot be considered singleton as it cannot be instantiated.   Look at [Can a Ruby module be described as a singleton class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352867/can-a-ruby-module-be-described-as-a-singleton-class) for more details.
- To make a class singleton, its better to use [`Singleton`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) module than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I know what is singleton. I asked not about singleton like a stdlib module, i'm asking about singleton like programming pattern in ruby. with using module, instead of class. Yes, module can not be instantiated, but it can store own module variables, and it is with out for realize singleton pattern